# Bower vs NPM: Which is better for installing AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I started a project without using bower (initially).  I'm using AngularJS, Browserify, Gulp, Node.js, etc. and did not install any other front-end dependencies yet.  Now that I want to make use of Bootstrap and FontAwesome, I was going to install and use Bower.  However, since AngularJS can be installed with both bower and npm...

Which is the better use case for installing AngularJS (Bower or NPM)? Why would one prevail over the other?  Does it just come down to personal preference?

Comment: If you want to use third party js plugins, most of them are available on npm and not on bower. So npm is a better option these days.

Comment: I don't know why people are down-voting this question.  While it's a little open ended and could lead to fan-boy discussions over one's preferred environment, you might take note that @BowlerDo0d is kinda new to SO. Rather than down-vote his question, take the time to explain how to better ask the question?  We were all in his shoes once before.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you already have your environment for this project setup to utilize npm, I'd not let a few more dependencies cause you to have to question that setup.  Especially things like Bootstrap & Font Awesome that can be embedded into your index.html via the CDN links.

Typically questions like these don't yield the expected answer.  There is no right answer across the board.  This is akin to asking:

> "Which do you prefer: A claw hammer or a ball-peen hammer?  I have this *thing* I am building."

There are only right answers within the context of your current setup, which you've already chosen by starting it with gulp & browserify.

But to play along...

Bower is good if you like:

- asynchronous (albeit, somewhat more exposed) dependencies
- less learning curve/setup, more "get it done"
- not having a bazillion options
- enjoy the AMD dependency model `define(['dep'], function (dep) {return function () {};});`

npm is good if you like:

- compiling your coffeescript/typescript/ into heftier javascript files (I haven't done this with Bower so I don't know if it offers some of the transpiling options, I assume it does)
- want to leverage node's existing extensive library of packages (via browserify/webpack)
- want more customization over how you build your app
- enjoy the Common JS dependency model `module.exports = ...`

I'm sure others can comment on the pros/cons of each.

Comment: or even pulled in with npm, assuming they have git repositories for the ones that don't have an npm entry.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is how they handle dependencies (nested for npm2 vs flat for bower)

It depends on your project, but in general I find it more "visible" if you start putting several versions of the same js library because dependencies... but the price is that you might end up banging your head a fair bit to find how to keep everyone happy with the same version.

As kelvin and helpermethod pointed out, npm3 does flatten the dependencies. At the end of the day, it's a matter of preferences, take whatever you prefer living with, both work ok

Comment: NPM3 also has flat dependencies.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the flat deps for NPM3?  I noticed the change, not knowing if it was something I had done or was done via switching versions via NVM.

Comment: @jusopi No, not possible. confirmed via an issue on github (too lazy to look it up again)